# Can't import AzureRM module in PowerShell while running from Python

Tags: python, powershell, azure

I wrote a PowerShell script which works fine when I run that from cmd as

```
powershell . C:\\scripts\\Azure.ps1; Review-Subscriptions -args xyz .\\output xxx-xxx-xxx 2017-23-07-01-04
```

Azure.ps1 uses some functions from AzureRM PowerShell module.

But when I run the same command from Python as,

```
path = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
script_path = "C:\\scripts\\Azure.ps1"
function_name = "Review-Subscriptions"
subscription_id = 'xxx-xxx-xxx'
file_path = '.\\output"'
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%d-%m-%H-%M")

cmd = '. %s; %s -args xyz %s %s %s' % \
      (script_path,
       function_name,
       file_path,
       subscription_id,
       now)
process = subprocess.Popen(
    [path, '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted',
     cmd
     ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.communicate()
```

In this case, PowerShell is not loading AzureRM module; which is causing entire script to fail.

How can we force to load the AzureRM module?

Tried following but didn't work.

a) added `Import-Module AzureRM` in the beginning of the file Azure.ps1 
b) changed cmd as

```
cmd = 'Import-Module AzureRM; . %s; %s( %s, %s, "%s")' % \
          (script_path,
           function_name,
           file_path,
           subscription_id,
           now)
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you running? I'm guessing something from 2.x given the print statement, but this would be helpful as `subprocess` has changed over time.

Comment: My Python version is 3.6.1,  p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted", "C:\\Users\\jason\\Desktop\\11\\jasonlogin.ps1"], stdout=sys.stdout) works for me, I can use ARM command to get the information, could you 
 please show your ps1 and the error logs?

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe Python2.7 yes it works, I needed to use python64  bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell modules were installed in the x64 system.

I had to just install Pythonx64 and use that to communicate with PowerShell.

I think the reason is that, when we use Pythonx86 then it communicates with Powershell by means of an x86 process, where as in the case Pyhonx64, it communicates with PowerShell using an x64 process.